‹‹ en venir ›› as an alternative to ‹‹ venir ››
I am reading a story which contains this sentence:

C'est après une violente crise de pneumonie, trois ans plus tôt, qu'il l'avait engagée à son service ; l'idée lui en était venue au cours de ses insomnies.

My question is this: why ‹‹ lui en était venue ›› rather than ‹‹ lui était venue ›› ?

On peut dire les deux. Ce en précise de quelle idée il s'agit (l'idée de l'engager à son service).

Grammaticalement, "en" pourrait correspondre à la "crise de pneumonies" : l'idée était venue de la crise.

@Graffito Les crises de pneumonie ne sont introduites que comme un évènement dans le passé de la narration? Après peut être interprété dans son aspect temporel uniquement.

@Graffito dans l'absolu, peut-être. La subordonnée qu'il l'avait engagée créerait une ambiguïté dans ce cas précis, que je lèverais p. ex. avec: l'idée lui était venue de cette crise, au cours de ses insomnies.

En takes the place of a clause introduced by de:
As a prepositional phrase to the noun idée

L'idée [de l'engager à son service] lui était venue au cours de ses insomnies

Or an adverbial phrase of reason (more far-fetched IMO):

L'idée lui était venue [de sa violente crise de pneumonie]

